# Разработчики Stack Overflow пользуются Stack Overflow для исправления багов?

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow

Почему-то стало очень интересно - Разработчики Stack Overflow пользуются Stack Overflow для исправления багов?

Comment: Разработчики Stack Overflow пользуются Stack Overflow для *добавления* багов.

Comment: Ну, мы конечно на 100% не знаем, но все вроде пользуются, почему бы им нет?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187449/